# How to configure Jenkins to show the groovy pipeline script names in the stack trace?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Currently Jenkins is obfuscating the script names in Jenkins' stack traces:

```
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 100
    at script15850717434352094028371.call(script15850717434352094028371.groovy:24)
    at script15850715592012138397318.run(script15850715592012138397318.groovy:27)
    at script1585071552378332044398.call(script1585071552378332044398.groovy:41)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
```

How would I configure jenkins to properly display the original script names:

```
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 100
    at doSomething2.call(doSomething2.groovy:24)
    at doSomething3.run(doSomething3.groovy:27)
    at doSomething1.call(doSomething1.groovy:41)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1) //This is the Jenkins File I believe
```

Comment: could you show the code that corresponds to this exception?

Comment: No, unfortunately. However, the exception doesn't seem to matter. The issue is that the stack trace is hiding the filenames where the issue happened. Only way to find the issue is to add additional logging to figure out where you are.